# C++ question about `using namespace ns` and explicit namespace `ns::my_method()`

Tags: c++

I declare a namespace in file ***test.h*** as follows：

```cpp
namespace dev {
    class test {
    public:
        test();
        ~test();
        int m_number;
    };
    int sumInt(int, int);
}
```

When I complete file ***test.cpp*** as follows：

```cpp
using namespace dev;
test::test() {
    m_number = 1;
}
test::~test() {}
int sumInt(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

There occurs an error ***"Unresolved external symbol dev::sumInt(int,int)"***

So I have to explicit introduce function sumInt to namespace dev like：

**int dev::sumInt(int a, int b);**

I'm very confused that when I using the namespace dev in file test.cpp,
why should method sumInt()  be explicit defined in namespace dev,but class test should't be?

Sorry my English is poor,I have try my best to describe the question clearly.

I hope someone can enlighten me.

Comment: After adding `#include "test.h"` to the top of test.cpp and `int main() { return 0; }` to the bottom of test.cpp it compiled just fine for me, what compiler are you using?

Comment: MSVC2017@asimes